# Azure Subscription URL Contains Other Admin's Email Address?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

I have two businesses and each has an Azure subscription. I'm an admin for each using my same MS email account.

Bill is only involved in one of the subscriptions, but when I log into my subscription "Local Happenings" (to which Bill should have no access) I still see his email address in the URL.

This picture shows it better:
https://db.tt/kvuccFOO

I'm wondering why this is, and if it could potentially be a problem.

My fear is that if he decides to cancel his business's account, then he will cancel mine or something.

I tried again to create a new subscription to verify I wasn't already logged into his subscription (I used a different browser), but it still shows his email address in the URL.

Anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE 1:

https://db.tt/QHJrfIno

I see that my subscription is under his "default directory". I never selected this when creating my subscription. How do I change this, and is it the culprit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What shows under the "Active Directory" tab in the management portal for each Subscription? When you say "MS email account" is that an old hotmail-type account or one registered via Office 365 or Azure?

The fact that the account showing in the URL has @XXX.onmicrosoft.com address suggests there is a link back to an Azure Active Directory (AAD) instance.  If this is shared between the subscriptions (potentially as a login from it was used to create on of the subscriptions) then this would be the cause.

You need to make sure a non-AAD account is an admin on the subscription so that removal of an associated Azure AD instance will not orphan the subscription.

Have a read of the AAD documentation here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn629581.aspx

Comment: No active directory setup in Azure for any subscription, I checked all. My email account is a gmail which I registered as an MS account. So I'm admin of my subscription and Bill isn't. Would mine swill be deleted if he removed his account? Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, your subscription will not be affected.  If Bill has no access to your subscription his actions will only apply to his.  The URL must just be a visual bug when you switch between subscriptions you are managing.  If you try the new portal it probably goes away :).